# Iterate through an Arraylist of Chars

Tags: java, iterator, char

I'm trying to make a method that inputs a string and returns it missspelled (by removing some random chars). For some reason my iterator is giving me a null error on the line that says id.remove(). Any ideas?

```
public static String getMissSpelledWord(String str) {
        Random random = new Random();
        char[] character = str.toCharArray();
        String misspelled = new String();


        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
            chars.add(character[i]);
        }

        for (Iterator < Character > id = chars.iterator(); id.hasNext();) {
            int remove = random.nextInt(3);
            if(remove == 0) {
                id.remove();
            }
        }

        for(char c : chars) {
            misspelled += c;
        }

        return misspelled;
    }
```

Comment: You need to call `id.next()` inside the `for` loop.  Otherwise, the first call to `remove` won't be pointing to anything.

Comment: BTW your entire generation of `chars` could be replaced with simply `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(str))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) without having invoked `Iterator.next()` (as the linked Javadoc notes *Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator*). Just add an `id.next()` in the loop body, like

```
for (Iterator<Character> id = chars.iterator(); id.hasNext();) {
    char ch = id.next(); // <-- add this.
    int remove = random.nextInt(3);
    if (remove == 0) {
        id.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, I just wasn't sure cause I didn't need to use it to check anything

Comment: @AZGames I should note that without that (assuming it did work) the loop would not end as `id.hasNext()` would continue to return true (since you never consume anything from the Iterator).

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to do this without an ArrayList by simply moving forward a random amount in your char array.

```
public static String getMisspelledWord(String str) {
    Random random = new Random();
    char[] character = str.toCharArray();
    String misspelled = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < character.length; i += random.nextInt(3) / 2 + 1) {
        misspelled += character[i];
    }
    return misspelled;
}
```

Comment: `i += random.nextInt(3) / 2 + 1` yikes.

Comment: @Alexander it should have a 1/3 chance of skipping over a given character which was the same chance of removing a character in AZ Games' original question

Comment: I get it, it's just something that you really need to look at and think. This could be much more readably implemented by keeping the loop counter incrementing by 1 (`i++`), and the body having `boolean shouldSkipNextCharacter = Math.random() < someProbability; if (shouldSkip) { i++; }`

Answer (score 0):

> Iterator.remove throws IllegalStateException - if the next method has
>   not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called
>   after the last call to the next method. and
>   UnsupportedOperationException - if the remove operation is not
>   supported by this iterator.

In your case, you should not get a null error, a `IllegalStateException` should be thrown.

Considering your use case, if you add `id.next();` before `id.remove();` till the iterator has elements, the loop will run and it will run till the chars is empty making your misspelled to be empty always.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public static String getMissSpelledWord(String string) {
    char charArray[] = string.toCharArray();
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < charArray.length; index++) {
        if (random.nextInt(3) == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        stringBuilder.append(charArray[index]);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Tested and working fine